# Azure SQL Server BCP -

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, bcp, azure-sql-server, azure-sql

I have a csv file with 3 columns

```
LastName
FirstName
EmpID
```

I was SQLLDR to load the data into Oracle database however I opted to use BCP to load the data into Azure sqlserver after the database migration to Azure SQL Server.

I am using the following command to generate the format

> bcp Database.Schema.Persons format nul -c -t, -f Persons.fmt -S tcp:demo.database.windows.net -U User01 -P P@$$word!

It has following format

```
13.0
3
1       SQLCHAR             0       255     ","      1     LastName               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       255     ","   2     FirstName              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLINT             0       255     "\r\n"   3     FirstName              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

However SQLLDR ctl file has the following functions

```
LPAD(:EmpID, 4, '0')
DATE "YYYY-MM-DD"
TIMESTAMP "YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6"
NVL(:LastName, '')
```

How do I accommodate in the BCP format file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I accommodate in the BCP format file?

You don't.  BCP into a staging table and INSERT ... SELECT to your final table to apply transformations.  Or stage the data in Azure Blob Storage and use [INSERT ... .SELECT . . . FROM OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#using-openrowset) to load the data into your target table.